# How to keep the zoomed view even after replotting set by NavigationToolbar2QT

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I want to create a PyQt5 Application that should contain a plot with a toolbar using matplotlib.
I want the user to use the zoom tool of the toolbar. So far so good, but now, I want to allow the user to replot the data while keeping the view as choosen by the user before (zoomed in a specific area e.g.).

So far, I was not able to do so. In the following code, instead of getting the isChecked(), I want to get the current zoom settings set by the user and apply them to the replotted plot.

I know the option should be there somewhere, because the old zoom view is accessible using the back and forward buttons, however, I do not understand how to access these old view settings and reapply them.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Create the plot and toolbar
        self.figure, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)

        # Create a layout for the plot and toolbar
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)

        # Create a central widget and set the layout
        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        # Create a button for replotting
        self.replot_button = QPushButton("Replot")
        self.replot_button.clicked.connect(self.replot)

        # Add the replot button to the layout
        layout.addWidget(self.replot_button)

    def replot(self):
        # Clear the current plot
        self.ax.clear()

        # Replot with different data
        x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        y = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
        self.ax.plot(x, y)

        # Redraw the canvas
        self.canvas.draw()

        # Retrieve the current zoom state
        zoom_state = self.toolbar._actions['zoom'].isChecked()
        if zoom_state:
            print("Zoom action is active")
        else:
            print("Zoom action is not active")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```